# setting up multiple postgresql 10 instances in same server

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-16.04

My company has two teams of devs, so I'm supposed to set up two postgresql instances on one machine on two different ports. We had a similar set-up on a test postgres VM but with versions 9.5/9.6. I installed postgres 10 without incident, and am trying to follow the instructions on the postgres10 docs [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/creating-cluster.html) but when I try to user initdb or pg_ctl I get the following:

```
postgres@DevPostgres:/usr/local$ whereis pg_ctl
pg_ctl: /usr/share/man/man1/pg_ctl.1.gz
postgres@DevPostgres:/usr/local$ whereis initdb
initdb: /usr/share/man/man1/initdb.1.gz
postgres@DevPostgres:/usr/local$ pg_ctl -D /usr/local/pgsql/data initdb
pg_ctl: command not found
```

I thought these two programs would have been installed in the first installation, but when I follow the chain of symbolic links to a .gz file and unzip it and try to use it I get the following:

```
root@DevPostgres:~# /usr/share/postgresql/10/man/man1/initdb.1 
/var/lib/postgresql/10-5433/
/usr/share/postgresql/10/man/man1/initdb.1: line 19: \" t
.\"     Title: initdb
.\"    Author: The PostgreSQL Global Development Group
.\" Generator: DocBook XSL Stylesheets v1.79.1 <http://docbook.sf.net/>
.\"      Date: 2018
.\"    Manual: PostgreSQL 10.3 Documentation
.\"    Source: PostgreSQL 10.3
.\"  Language: English
.\"
.TH "INITDB" "1" "2018" "PostgreSQL 10.3" "PostgreSQL 10.3 Documentation"
.\" -----------------------------------------------------------------
.\" * Define some portability stuff
.\" -----------------------------------------------------------------
.\" ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.\" http://bugs.debian.org/507673
.\" http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/groff/2009-02/msg00013.html
.\" ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.ie \n(.g .ds Aq \(aq
.el       .ds Aq : No such file or directory
/usr/share/postgresql/10/man/man1/initdb.1: line 20: .": command not found
/usr/share/postgresql/10/man/man1/initdb.1: line 21: .": command not found
/usr/share/postgresql/10/man/man1/initdb.1: line 22: .": command not found
/usr/share/postgresql/10/man/man1/initdb.1: line 23: .": command not found
/usr/share/postgresql/10/man/man1/initdb.1: line 24: .nh: command not found
/usr/share/postgresql/10/man/man1/initdb.1: line 25: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/share/postgresql/10/man/man1/initdb.1: line 25: `.\" disable justification (adjust text to left margin only)'
```

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Was postgres installed from package or built from source? And what OS do you use?

Comment: From package and on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Try to run initdb as postgres user: "sudo su - postgres" then "initdb -D /path/to/data/directory"

Comment: still getting `command not found`

Comment: do you have something under /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/?

Comment: It seems that ubuntu distributes postgres with some modifications. Quick search shows that there should be pg_createcluster instead of direct initdb call for creating new instances. I recommend you to search for ubuntu specific tutorial.

Comment: That helped. I use `pg_cluster 10 india` to initialize the second instance. Now I'm trying to start it!